# Stop showing a certain file extension in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mavericks

I've got a question about OS X file extensions.  I know on individual files, I can right click, select Get Info and then tell it not to display that file's extension.  Is there a terminal command or other way to stop showing certain file extensions altogether?

Something in the terminal like:

```
$ sudo hidefileextension *.por
```

The extension I'm trying to hide is `.por`, which is the extension that [Hero Lab](http://www.wolflair.com/?context=hero_lab&page=pathfinder_roleplaying_game) puts after its character portfolios for the [Pathfinder RPG](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG).

Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

The Finder stores hidden extensions as an extended attribute, which can be modified using the `xattr` command. First, if you have a file with a hidden extension, you should see an @ sign appended to the permissions and the xattr item in the listing, and then you can view it using the command:

```
$ ls -l@
-rw-r--r--@   1 user  staff     0B Dec 19 23:41 test.txt
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32B 
$ xattr -px com.apple.FinderInfo test.txt
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
$
```

Notice the 1 in the top line? That's the hex of the hidden extension flag. There may be other options depending on the file.

To apply the attribute, you can use this command:

```
xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo '0000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' test.txt
```

But an important thing to note is that if you already have an xattr on the file (designated by the @ sign in the permissions field) then using that command will *overwrite* any other xattrs. You have to take the hex representation and bit mask it over the current xattr for com.apple.FinderInfo. I'm not sure how to do that in bash, but you could probably do it with a Python script or something.

I'd recommend taking the command and putting it in your .bashrc if you're going to be using it a lot.